# FULL TEXT search methods by tags or text fields and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have this MySQL table

```
id | description | tags         |
1    hi man       tag1;tag2;tag3
2    hi woman     tag0;tag2;tag9
```

I would like to know which is the best practice to build up a simple search engine?
Is possible to have search keywords priority with only MySQL queries or need i somenthing more complex like elasticsearch, lucene, sphinx, etc .. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate tags with a space, not with a semi-colon. Then add FULLTEXT indices to your table.

Geeky resource: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

More friendly resource: http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/full-text-searching-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Fulltext search using MySQL

See Example :- http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

But as a Performance, a Full text search is a slow search as compared to elasticsearch, lucene, sphinx, etc.

So if you want very fast performance use elasticsearch, lucene, sphinx etc. For normal speed, you can use simple Full Text Search

Comment: rationalboss just cause was first

Comment: replyed first i mean before of you, but your answer too should be marked :)